# How to make an ajax jquery request to get data from a Django ListView?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a base template in which I have a header and in that header, there are some link buttons that I would like to change the appearance of when clicked, for this it would be necessary to use ajax to avoid reloading the page. The request must be a GET to display the updated page data.

That is, the ajax script must be done in my base.html at the button click event, to load the template that extends the base. Right?

The view:

```
class HomeListView(ListView):
    model = Cars
    template_name = 'cars.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'

    def get_queryset(self):
        cars = super().get_queryset().order_by('model')
        return cars
```

The data in the template cars.html (which extends base.html) is processed in this way:

```
<div class="car-grid">
    {% if cars %}
        {% for car in cars %}
        <div class="car-card">
            <img src="{{ car.photo.url }}" alt="{{ car.model }} - {{ car.brand }}">
            <h2> {{ car.brand }} {{ car.model }} </h2>
            <p> {{ car.factory_year }} - $ {{ car.value }} </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p class="no-results">No results found. </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

What is the smartest way to make this ajax request to get the updated cars context variable? Is there any way to pass it to all html in cars.html at once?